# Mix of groovy and powershell variables in script - Jenkins

Tags: powershell, jenkins-pipeline

Am struggling to get teh following to work in a jenkins pipeline:

```
stage('Initiate Build Variables') {
            steps {
                withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: '27f6313e-1d43-4552-8869-adea55dacce2', usernameVariable: 'ELEVATED_USER', passwordVariable: 'ELEVATED_PASSWORD']]) {
                powershell label: '', returnStdout: true, script: """
                \$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "${ELEVATED_PASSWORD}" -AsPlainText -Force
                Write-output \$secpasswd
                Write-output "date"
                \$mycreds = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @(${ELEVATED_USER},\$secpasswd)
                Write-Output \$mycreds
                """
                }
                }
        }
```

I end up getting the following in the output of the pipeline:

```
Masking supported pattern matches of %ELEVATED_USER% or %ELEVATED_PASSWORD%
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] powershell (hide)
 > git branch -a -v --no-abbrev # timeout=10
 > git checkout -b master ea91b828649ae51629db78b7ada9b490ff682084
At E:\Jenkins\workspace\onprem-2012@tmp\durable-abb32110\powershellScript.ps1:5 char:117
+ ... anagement.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @(****,$secpass ...
+                                                                 ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument


[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
```

It feels like it is not passing the $secpasswd variable correctly to create the pscredential object but I am at a bit of a loss as I am unsure of the correct syntax for the mix of the groovy variable and my runtime defined powershell variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax looks good to me except for:

> ```
> -ArgumentList @(${ELEVATED_USER},\$secpasswd)
> ```

It should be:

> ```
> -ArgumentList @("${ELEVATED_USER}",\$secpasswd)
> ```

You have to quote the first argument, because it is a Groovy variable in a PowerShell array constructor. Without quoting, the groovy compiler would evaluate the string of the PowerShell script like this:

```
-ArgumentList @(TheActualUserName, $secpasswd)
```

This is not valid PowerShell syntax.

Comment: thanks.  been driving me nuts.  not quite sure what the difference between the two is though?